# Haskell code to function dependency graph

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to use GHC or something else to generate a function call dependency graph of a Haskell program? I'm specifically interested in extracting information about what functions call / rely on what other functions.

Note: I'm not asking about figuring out module dependencies.

Note 2: [SourceGraph](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph) seems to be abandoned.